# React - table created incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table in React where the user can add a variable number of rows.

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>List Names</th>
            <th>List Full Names</th>
            <th>List Descriptions</th>
        </tr>
        {this.displayTableBody()}
    </table>

    <button style={{display:'inline-block'}} type="button" 
            className="btn btn-primary btn-small" onClick={this.addList}>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The rows are added by the `displayTableBody` method:

```
displayTableBody: function() {
    var rows = Array.apply(null, Array(this.state.rowNr)).map(
        function(e1, index) {
            return <ListInput key={index} ref={index}/>
        }
    );
    return(<div>{ rows }</div>);
}
```

One row is made of a `ListInput` component, which has the following `render` method:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{this.displaySimpleInputField(
                "List Name(<15 characters - A-Z, 0-9 and _ only)", this.setListName, "input")}</td>
            <td>{this.displaySimpleInputField(
                "List Full Name(<75 characters)", this.setListFullName, "input")}</td>
            <td>{this.displaySimpleInputField(
                "List Description(<225 characters)", this.setListDescription, "input")}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

However, when I add a row, it is placed above the table header:

[image]

Comment: check in inspect weather your  `return(<div>{ rows }</div>);` line means `<div>` cause error or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting `div` element directly inside a table, which is not correct html and it does break the layout, [placing that element at the top of the table](https://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/).

I would suggest restructuring your code as follows, and consider using [`times` function from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#times):

```
displayTableBody: function() {
  var rows = times(this.state.rowNr).map(
    function(index) {
      return <ListInput key={index} ref={index}/>
    }
  );
  return(<tbody>{ rows }</tbody>);
}
```

And the table

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>List Names</th>
      <th>List Full Names</th>
      <th>List Descriptions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {this.displayTableBody()}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with tables, it is doubly important to write valid HTML, otherwise you get weird results like this. Specifically, the correct structure of a table is kinda like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Specifically, I'm pretty sure you can't place a `div` directly in `table`, like you do with your `displayTableBody` method. Try to rewrite your component to follow the HTML [standard](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), I believe that's what causes your problem.